# How to permanently install MEAN.io package

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gruntjs, mean.io

I've installed a *Contrib* MEAN.io package to my project via the instructions [here](http://mean.io/#!/packages). The command line is like so:

```
mean install <package-name>
```

That added the package to my locally application instance, and it runs there fine. I can see that the package is now in my `node_modules` directory, and it's compiling in OK. But none of the project configuration files (things that would actually get checked into source control) reflect that the package was installed. `Gruntfile.js`, `package.json`, and `bower.json` are all unchanged after the install command. Further, when I deploy to a different environment the package is not present on the new environment.

How do I permanently alter my project to always include an external MEAN.io package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently deployment of a MEAN.io *Contrib* package involves adding it to the `package.json` file manually:

https://github.com/linnovate/mean-admin#deployment